# For string manipulations, string or sitring buffer is faster?

Tags: java, string

I need to do lot of following code in program

```
int index=temp.lastIndexOf("\\n== External links ==\\");
        System.out.println( temp.substring(index))
```

Indexof,substring,contains so these manipulations will be better in stringbuffer or string?

If so why can you elaborate me?

Comment: Try both and compare the performance. We can't tell how such tradeoffs play out in your codebase. Only you can answer this question definitively.

Comment: "a lot" as in hundreds, thousands, millions? What is the typical string length?

Comment: In the long term, and again, depending on your codebase, I think working with String would be faster. This approach would consume more memory though since String is a particular class with its dedicated memory area within the JVM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no `contains` or StringBuffer on StringBuilder.
The indexOf and substring are delegated to String itself.
StringBuffer and StringBuilder are faster for concatenation, but for looking into the String: take the String class itself

Answer (score 2):

`String.substring` does not create a new string, only indexes into the original string, thus avoiding the cost of copying string content. So if this is all you need to do, `String` is probably enough (and it is simpler to use - especially as `StringBuffer` / `StringBuilder` has no `contains` method).

OTOH you should definitely not use `StringBuffer` as it is synchronized, which brings with it a performance penalty - consider `StringBuilder` instead if you are using Java5 or newer.

In the end, the only sure way for you to know is to measure each option in your own environment, with real data.

Answer (score 0):

Using StringBuffer or StringBuilder is advised over String when lots of string manipulations are to be performed, since using String will leave you with a lot of unreferenced String objects in the "string constant pool".

Furthermore StringBuilder is preferred over StringBuffer (though they have the exact same API) coz its methods are not thread-safe (i.e synchronized) hence they perform faster.